# change the Top and Left in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

i have latest hightcharts `2.3.5` and i have many charts in one page .

i have tried with `marginTop` and `spacingTop` but they didnt seem to move the chart inside the rendered div . but with firebug i noticed that there is `Top` and `Left`  which are generated from the script `highcharts.js` and from those left and top i could move the chart as i wanted (this just in firebug) .But there is no settings on how to change the top and left in highcharts API or settings.

please how can i be able to change the `Top` and `Left` for every chart i have.

any other information let me know and i will add it.

EDIT.

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'wfa_b', type: 'line',width: 760,height:null,marginRight: 5,marginBottom: 24 , 
            marginTop:46},
```

thanks for help

**EDIT**

in other way i have background of the render div but i dont want this background to fit exactly the chart , i want to position my chart where i want on the background image of the div , hope this clear

[SQLFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FAWLa/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            borderWidth: 2,
            marginLeft: 150,
            marginTop: 100
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/chart/marginleft/)

[Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.marginLeft)

**Edit** (after comments):

As OP clarified, he needs `marginLeft` and `marginTop` in the `render div` itself, not in the chart area.

Assuming you have `div` with `id='container'`,

```
#container { 
    padding: 20px;

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FAWLa/3/)

**EDIT 2 :** (after comments):

OP didnt want to resize the chart which `padding` was doing.

So, use this,

```
#container .highcharts-container {
   top: 100px !important;
   left: 100px !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FAWLa/8/)

Comment: as i said , `marginLeft` and `marginTop` they dont help. its just help the `Top` and `Left` which are generatec automatically,edited my answer and added example

Comment: can you create a fiddle of the problem ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FAWLa/2/  as u see marginTop is just to make chart litle short , can you move the whole chart to the left (not longing it move as it is )

Comment: in other way i have background of the render div but i dont want this background to fit exactly the chart , i want to position my chart where i want on the background image of the div , hope this clear

Comment: in that case add `padding` to `render div` or create chart in child `div`. See my edit

Comment: no , i dont know if you understand me . i dont want touch the background of the div , i want to touch the specially `Top` and `Left` of the generated div .

Comment: just add `padding-left` and `padding-top`

Comment: do by firebug , you will find top and left tags , then you can move the chart from them

Comment: i said i dont want move the backround of the container div . i want it fixed , i want to move the chart itself from those top and left

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24671/discussion-between-jashwant-and-echo-me)

Comment: cant use your Css of TOP and Left because the Js is much power. it comes the top and left of the Js not of the css . so i think the javascript is powerful . its better if there is option where to control also top and left in settings not only generated from the script. +1 for the help i have moved the chart by marginLeft and marginRight . and now im getting wrong Margin IE :(

Comment: Its not the in the hand of js to move left and top. Js adds the inline css which has more priority than css we apply. Thats why, I added `!important` attribute. Do apply these and you are good to go

Comment: ok i fixed it with all margins ,(marginTop, ...)thanks for the help .